# Vaadin 8 Drag & Drop - how to switch items in vertical layout?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I need to accomplish very simple drag and drop of panels in vertical layout.

- each panel is set as DragSourceExtension
- vertical layout is set as DropTargetExtension

Now when I have a several panels in vertical layout and I drag panel above another one and drop it my dropListener runs and here I'm  not sure how to manage what I require. I simply need panel to move on proper place based on mouse pointer. Can anyone share some code how to accomplish this using Vaadin 8.2 ? Should I switch panels manualy? If so how can I detect the place mouse points to in the vertical layout?

```
dropTarget.addDropListener(event -> {
  Optional<AbstractComponent> dragSource = event.getDragSourceComponent();
  if (dragSource.isPresent() ) {
      # I can remove dragged panel from layout using this code
      fieldsLayout.removeComponent(dragSource.get());

      ## how to place dragged panel into proper place ??

  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's overkill, but in Vaadin 7 we always used the DragDropLayouts addon to simplify code.
We also used it in Vaadin 8 projects recently and it just works ;)

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/dragdroplayouts